# WinAPI Multithreaded Application

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm wanting to create a WinAPI application/window and since I don't want my execution to block while waiting for messages, I was planning to have 2 threads; a main thread and an application thread. The application thread would create the window (CreateWindowEx) then block in a message loop.

My predicament comes from the main thread wanting to modify a part of the application. For example, changing the style, size, etc. To keep the application thread-safe, I would assume it is best to keep that kind of code on the same thread. My first idea is to post a message from the main thread so the application thread unblocks and can handle the request and then block again. However, I'm not sure if sending a message from a separate thread is safe and I have had a hard time finding an answer to that online. There may also be better solutions that I'm not considering. I would appreciate any help or feedback.

Comment: for this tasks you not need have 2(or more threads) - single thread more than enough. use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` bassed message loop

Comment: Yes, you can post (or send) messages between threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a message with `SendMessage` and/or `PostMessage` across threads is safe and supported.

SendMessage waits while the other thread processes the message and PostMessage does not wait. There are other differences between the two but the important thing to remember in your case is that you cannot do

```
...
if (whatever)
{
  char buffer[100];
  strcpy(buffer, "hello world");
  PostMessage(g_MyWindow, WM_APP, 0, (LPARAM) buffer); // BUG, must use SendMessage
}
...
```

because the buffer could go out of scope before the other thread has processed the message.

In general, all the Windows functions that deal with windows like `MoveWindow` and `GetWindowRect` are thread safe. Most of them can also be used on windows in another process...

Comment: A few notes: `1` While technically thread safe, window mutators should always be called from the thread, that created the window. This is explicitly spelled out for [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx), for example. `2` Sending messages across threads should be done using `SendMessageTimeout` to prevent deadlocks. `3` While `SendMessage` is waiting the target to return, it will still dispatch inbound cross-thread messages.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes SendMessage to other threads is risky if the target is not processing messages but you generally only guard against it when dealing with other processes, you just assume your own code is bug free ;) Sending a message from a worker thread to your UI thread should never be a problem.

Comment: Just because a thread runs in your process doesn't mean that it's your code.